# Becuase of the better performance of Magento 2, Can we reduce number of servers?

Tags: magento-2.1, nginx, server-setup

Currently we are using 7 servers for our Magento 1 production site, those are all working under load balancer.
Now we are planning on Magento 2 upgrade with php7. Because of the php7 and magento 2 better performance compare to php 5.5 and magento 1,

Is it advisable to reduce the servers to 5? Will we get the same results of the existing system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:** I benchmarked Magento 1.9.3.2 vs 2.1.4 myself. **1.9.3.2 beats 2.1.4 on every front.**

[image]

details here https://www.goivvy.com/blog/magento-1924-magento-214-performance-benchmark

OLD:

**probably not. always test test test before you make radical changes.**

you are right about one thing - php7 will get things faster.

who told you magento 1.x performance is worse than magento 2.x? having FPC built-in doesn't make magento 2.x better than magento 1.x in terms of performance.

here go and read the benchmark tests https://blog.amasty.com/magento-1-vs-magento-2-performance-comparison-speed-test-results/

the final picture thanks to Amasty team (less is better):

[image]

another good source for your consideration https://www.magecore.com/blog/news/magento-ce-1-9-vs-magento-ce-2-0-performance-comparison

Also see this guide on how to [speed up magento 2](https://www.goivvy.com/blog/speed-up-magento).

Comment: Magento 1.x speed also looks fine for us. But upgrading to new version, we are looking for some benefits over infrastructure costs. Thatswhy raising this question to make sure.

Comment: did you check the graph above. your speed will deteriorate if you move to M2.

Comment: the graph result taken using Magento 2.0.0 which don't have support from Magento now. In the latest version Magento 2.1.x, as per their white paper the load time looks better compare to Magento 1.x

Comment: would you share that white paper results? link maybe?

Comment: though it mentioned as magento 2.0, the result is good, https://magento.com/sites/default/files/White%20Paper%20-%20Magento%202.0%20Performance%20and%20Scalability%2003.31.16.pdf

Comment: Sir, this paper compares Enterprise Editions. are you on EE? EE!=CE so please do not mistake others.

Comment: but stand still - I am going to benchmark CE 1.9.2.4 vs 2.1.4. results soon

Comment: see my benchmark results https://www.goivvy.com/blog/magento-1924-magento-214-performance-benchmark 1.9.3.2 beats 2.1.4 on every front.

Answer (score 0):

Magneto 2 performance is relay bad, with a lot of custom extensions it doesn't work well - serve response time 3-5 sec. Core functionality also twice slower than M1. Konstntin Gerasimov is right! Check his post with performance test: 
https://medium.com/@egorshytikov/magento-2-3-2-vs-magento-1-9-4-php-core-performance-test-b267570b8b3

[image: MAgento 2 Performance vs MAgento 1]